# Unity3d: How do I lock a background image, so the player moves and never gets out of the background?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to make a sky jump game, where you have to jump on different platforms, and when you fall off the screen (y-axis), you die and start over. But when the camera follows my player and reaches the height of the background, the background is gone.
I have tried to set the layer to "lock", but it didn´t work. Do you have any ideas?

I have an image showing background layer: [background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6VhR.png)

Comment: Just make it camera's child.

Comment: Glad it helped. )

Answer (score 1):

Add another Camera to Hierarchy that will only display the background

Answer (score 0):

If the background is consistently continuous I would just have the position of the background update once the player reached a certain height. This way, you never truly reach the "top" of the background and are only concerned with whether or not they meet your fail condition.

The pesudo-code for that might be something like this:

```
void Update() {
   if ((background height - player z) < limit) {
       background.pos = new pos
   }
 }
```

Comment: This solution is only good when the background is symmetrical, but as he says He wants a stationary wallpaper, then this might not help.